# update node.js and check version at root successfully, but after exit root, nothing change

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

update node.js and check version at root successfully but after exit root, nothing change

server version: ubuntu 18.04

My node.js version is v6.17.0

When I update node.js to the latest version without root, it does not work
when I using root to update, and check the version using `node -v` after the update, it works. Version change to v10.15.3

but after I exit root and using `node -v` again, node.js version had not been updated, it still showing v6.17.0

How can I update successfully?

Comment: are you using nvm to installing node?

Comment: oh.  after I use nvm. Done and thx